# Error: undefined Unable to resolve module './Home' from 'AppNavigator.js' in React Native

Tags: react-native, import, module

I am unable to solve the issue. Why it is happening? Also changed the import like 
    import Home from './src/screen/Home'; but the result is same.

Link of Screen shot of error stack is given:

[image]

[image]

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Profile from './src/screen/Profile';

class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home'
   };
render() {
 return (
  <View style={{ 
   flex: 1,
   alignItems:'center',
   justifyContent:'center'
  }}>
<Button title="Go to Profile screen"
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}
 />
  </View>
);
}
}
export default Home;
```

Profile.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './src/screen/Home';


class Profile extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Profile'
   };
 render() {
 return (
  <View style={{ 
   flex: 1,
   alignItems:'center',
   justifyContent:'center'
  }}>
<Button title="Go to Home screen"
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
   />
  </View>
);
}
}
export default Profile;
```

Comment: share your error stack here

Comment: i have attached the screen shot but it is not showing. Instead a error stack link. Please see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to import the home and profile with wrong path. Try the below code and it will work as expected.

```
import Home from './src/screen/Home'
import Profile from './src/screen/Profile'
```

> As your both the screens are inside the src directory, that's why you
>   are getting the error

Also,

when you are in the same directory just use ./<<*file-name*>> to access the file. And when you have to access the files which is outside the current directory then you have to use ../path. so change both the import for both the files respectively.
 
`import Profile from './Profile';`

`import Homefrom './Home';`

More you can read [here](https://medium.com/react-native-zone/english-react-native-import-with-absolute-path-2fc93faca1bb) about absolute path for static files in react native

I Hope this works....Thanks :)

Comment: giving the same error. Please see this screenShot above.

Comment: share you profile and home files code @user12371061

Comment: please check...i have added the fix for the issue...Hope it works Thanks :) @user12371061

Comment: as a new user you should upvote the answer as well.. Thanks :) @user12371061

Answer (score 0):

The path to the `Home` screen inside `AppNavigator.js` should be `import Home from './src/screen/Home'`. This is because the `src` directory is in the same directory as `AppNavigator.js`. The same change should be made for the `Profile` screen.

The path for importing `Profile` inside `Home.js` should be `import Profile from './Profile'`. This is because the file is in the same directory as `Home.js`. The same change should be made for importing `Home` inside of `Profile.js`.

Comment: @user12371061 have you tried resetting the cache? Last I checked, the command was `react-native start --reset-cache`.

Comment: @user12371061 could you include some of the `Home` file in your question?

Comment: Home.js is added above

Comment: @user12371061 check out the second part of my answer. `Home` should use a different import path for `Profile`.

Comment: I didn't get u. Please explain.

Comment: @user12371061 if the imports still aren't working for you, I've updated my answer with a little more information.